# Inno Setup: RegQueryStringValue isn't working

Tags: windows, inno-setup, pascalscript, .net-4.8

Using Inno Setup, I'm trying to check to see if the .NET 4.8 runtime is installed on a Windows computer. If it is not installed, I run the .NET 4.8 runtime installer exe file. [According to Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/migration-guide/how-to-determine-which-versions-are-installed), you can check the registry at a certain location and look at a certain value to see which specific version of .NET is installed. Inno Setup has a function called `RegQueryStringValue` which grabs a value from the registry:

https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_regquerystringvalue

I am following that API correctly, as far as I'm aware. I have also confirmed, using regedit, that this registry key and value do exist on my system. However, when I run Inno Setup, it fails to find the registry value. Here is my code:

```
function IsDotnet48Installed: boolean;
var
  valueStr: string;
  valueInt: integer;
begin
  if RegQueryStringValue(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, 'SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v4\Full', 'Release', valueStr) then
  begin
    MsgBox('.NET 4.8 registry value is: "' + valueStr + '"', mbInformation, MB_OK);
    valueInt := StrToInt(valueStr);
    if valueInt >= 528040 then
      result := true
    else
      result := false
  end
else
  MsgBox('Unable to find .NET 4.8 registry key', mbInformation, MB_OK);
end;
```

When the above code is ran, the `RegQueryStringValue` function returns false, and I thus get the message box that says "Unable to find .NET 4.8 registry key". I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

@LexiLi 's comment to the original question is the answer.

Instead of using the function `RegQueryStringValue` I used the function `RegQueryDWordValue`. Worked on the first try.

https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_regquerydwordvalue